# DevOps API search queries syntax

Tags: api, azure-devops

We need to search "queries" by name and author. Following [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/search%20queries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) we came up with this attempt:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/wit/queries?api-version=5.1&$filter=createdBy=Fernando
```

But it returns

```
{
   "value": [],
   "hasMore": false
}
```

Other unsuccessful attempts were:

```
$filter="createdBy"="Fernando"
$filter={createdBy=Fernando}
$filter=createdBy:Fernando
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lack of detailed documents about how the filters should be defined. I failed to use filter query parameter too. I end up using powershell scripts to filter the with the response result returned by [Query List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API. Query list api will return the query folders. you can specify the `$depth` parameter to get children queries.

Below scripts will get the queries filtered by the createdBy.

```
$query ="https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/wit/queries?`$depth=2&api-version=5.1"

$connectionToken="PAT"


$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result7 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $query -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get

$queryfolder = $result7.value[0]

$child = $queryfolder.children | Where-Object {$_.createdBy.displayName  -Like "<name>"}
```

Hope you find above helpful!

Comment: It's unbelievable that Microsoft has such a poor API. Thanks for your help!